# Converting Spark-kafka InputDStream to Array[Bytes]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

I am using scala & consuming data from Kafka using below Spark Streaming approach:

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(_._2)
```

Above variable returns InputDStream through which I am able to see data in raw/binary format using below code:
println(line)

But I need to apply avro format(schema available) on raw/binary format in order to see data in expected json format. In order to apply avro format, I need to to convert above InputDStream to Array[Bytes] which is used by avro.

Can someone please let me know convert InputDStream to Array[Bytes]?

Or

If you know some better way to apply avro schema on InputDStream(of spark Streaming), please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to do. The first is use the `DefaultDecoder` for Kafka which gives you an `Array[Byte]` for the value type:

```
val lines: DStream[(String, Array[Byte])] = 
  KafkaUtils
   .createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

And then you need to apply your Avro deserialization logic via an additional `map`:

```
lines.map { case (_, bytes) => avroDeserializer.deserialize(bytes) }
```

Where `avroDeserializer` is an arbitrary class of yours which knows how to create your type from Avro bytes.

I personally use [avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s) to get case class deserialization via macros.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks! I just needed value of DStream as Array[Byte], so I fetched it using: val lines: DStream[(Array[Byte])] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
     String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](
     ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(_._2)